# Adding <data> tag to Intent-Filter in Action not being honored

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've searched documentation, but I'm missing something obvious. Or am trying to do something backwards.

What I have is the main activity, that's fired from the launcher and widgets. I have a **second activity** that I'd like to be fired off when a URL of a specific pattern is attempted to be opened. Here's the two activity definitions:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainMapScreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activities.ViewDatasheet" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:label="@string/app_name" android:process=":BMMapsDatasheet">
    <meta-data android:name="Main Screen" android:value=".activities.MainMapScreen" />
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.ngs.noaa.gov" android:pathPattern="\\/cgi-bin\\/ds_mark.prl\\?PidBox\\=([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Like the above, url's aren't intercepted. Even if I have nothing in the data but the scheme and host, I don't get the prompt to select my app.

As a test, I copied the browsable and  to the main activity, and when I do that, the icon disappears form the launcher altogether. (And I still get no prompt when trying to hit the URL.

All the examples I find has the  in the main activity, not a secondary activity, so.. I'm not sure if I'm missing some flags or such.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. If you want me to post the whole Manifest, let me know.

--Mike.

**Edit**: After adding @iturki suggestions, there was no change. however - if I **also** added `<category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />` to the action to handle the URLs, that worked. None of the examples I saw with the  had that category, so I'm not yet sure if it would affect other operations of the activities in my application or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a [*`VIEW action`*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) to your second Activity's `<intent-filter>`:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
```

And I think you might want to add your Intent to the [DEFAULT category](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DEFAULT) too:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
```

I'm not sure if it is important but all the `<intent-filter>`s have this category.

Comment: Hmm.. that's interesting. Did what you recommended, and here's the result -
Using the default browser, I get an app picker - but the only two options are Browser and Boat (my other browser installed). So, it's progress!
Using the Boat browser, it does not give me a picker dialog.

Comment: Yup - no dice. I did get it tho, not sure if it will potentially mess up other things. See my modified question above.

Comment: Also, ignore the comment about Boat browser. Both Boat Browser and Dolphin browsers apparently don't check registered intents that way.

Comment: @Coyttl Nice to know that works. And I don't think adding this category will affect other activities. If it will affect something it will be the activity you put it on.